# Reliably detect Windows in Python

Tags: python, windows, platform-detection

I'm working on a couple of Linux tools and need to prevent installation on Windows, since it depends on FHS and is thus rendered useless on that platform. The `platform.platform` function comes close but only returns a string.

Unfortunately I don't know what to search for in that string for it to yield a reliable result. Does anyone know what to search for or does anyone know of another function that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
```

Answer (score 72):

For those that came here looking for a way to detect Cygwin from Python (as opposed to just detecting Windows), here are some example return values from `os.name` and `platform.system` on different platforms

```
OS/build     | os.name | platform.system() 
-------------+---------+-----------------------
Win32 native | nt      | Windows
Win32 cygwin | posix   | CYGWIN_NT-5.1*
Win64 native | nt      | Windows
Win64 cygwin | posix   | CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64*
Linux        | posix   | Linux
```

From this point, how to distinguish between Windows native and Cygwin should be obvious although I'm not convinced this is future proof.

* version numbers are for XP and Win7 respectively, do not rely on them

Comment: @JaceBrowning: fair enough, we are probably using different version of Cygwin or Python... This is where the "not-futureproof" note comes in :)

Comment: the difference is probably that my Python installation is part of Windows, not through Cygwin?

Comment: @JaceBrowning: which I call "native" in my post. What exactly is your exact output from `os.name` and `platform.system()`?

Comment: os.name=='nt'
platform.system()=='Windows'

Comment: So that's exactly what I listed in the table above for the "native" Python builds that go on Windows. No contradiction.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Just worth nothing that the above only works when the python binary used is the cygwin binary and not a native windows one.

Comment: `platform.system` can also return `'Java'` and `os.name` can also return `'posix'` `'os2'` `'ce'` `'java'` and `'riscos'`

Answer (score 15):

On my Windows box, `platform.system()` returns `'Windows'`.

However, I'm not sure why you'd bother. If you want to limit the platform it runs on technologically, I'd use a white-list rather than a black-list.

In fact, I wouldn't do it technologically at all since perhaps the next release of Python may have `Win32/Win64` instead of `Windows` (for black-listing) and `*nix` instead of `Linux` (for white-listing).

My advice is to simply state what the requirements are and, if the user chooses to ignore that, that's their problem. If they ring up saying they got an error message stating "Cannot find FHS" and they admit they're running on Windows, gently point out to them that it's not a supported configuration.

Maybe your customers are smart enough to get FHS running under Windows so that your code will work. They're unlikely to appreciate what they would then consider an arbitrary limitation of your software.

This is a problem faced by software developers every day. Even huge organizations can't support *every* single platform and configuration out there.

Comment: +1, good answer and I agree. Detecting that FHS isn't available is a far better method than detecting the OS and making an assumption, and it's safer (after all, having someone hack around your platform limit is going to fail *anyway*!).

Comment: +1, yes a whitelist is preferable as the corner cases are nasty. Running under Cygwin on a Windows box I get `platform.system()` returning `CYGWIN_NT-5.2-WOW64`. That wouldn't have been my first guess!

Comment: `ask for forgiveness not permission`. very good recommendation. Example: preemptive refusal of installer programs are the worst thing programmer can impose on us. E.g.: trying to be all clever and checking disk space is a big no no. I could be installing on a symlink.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'nt'
```

"The name of the operating system dependent module imported. The following names have currently been registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'mac', 'os2', 'ce', 'java', 'riscos'." (c) http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.name

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    #yourcodehere
```

Comment: At least on my box `os.name` returns `posix` when running under Cygwin, and `nt` when running under native windows build

Comment: Yes, Cygwin is a pain, but for original story this behavior is accepted (if not desired).

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
import platform

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    # Don't have Windows handy, but I'd expect "Win32" or "Windows" for it
```

**Edit:** Just saw that you tried `platform.platform()`...`platform.system()` will work better for this case.  Trust me, use it.  Dark corners lie in platform detection.

`distutils` will do this too, if you ask it nicely.

You could always do something bad like `os.path.exists()` on a Windows file...but `platform` is as reliable as it gets in the Python standard library.

**Edit 2:** Another helpful answerer pointed out `platform.system()` is exactly equal to "Windows" on his Windows machine.

Comment: I also don't have Windows handy, but this function returns 'Linux' on my pc. The docs seem to mention 'Windows', so I guess I will just go with that and hope that it covers all cases.

Comment: It should.  See Pax's answer.

Answer (score 1):

From `help(platform)`

```
system()
    Returns the system/OS name, e.g. 'Linux', 'Windows' or 'Java'.

    An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.
```