# what is os.name on Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

[When to use os.name, sys.platform, or platform.system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4553129/4279) suggests that `os.name` might be `'nt'`.
[Reliably detect Windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387222/4279) suggests that `os.name` is `'posix'`.

Is it `'posix'` or `'nt'`?

Comment: So...is this a question?

Comment: @KevinGuan The question is in the title. Though it's easy to find out if you have a windows box or a VM.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Okay, I've seen the title but I thought that's too easy to know that...Sorry.

Comment: It might depend on the specific Python build.

Comment: why the downvote? Do you think it is too easy? Are you sure? Can you *guarantee* that `os.name == 'posix'`? (have you a link to docs that promise that? Can you confirm it by running it on various combinations of Python/Windows/Cygwin versions?)

Comment: **Excellent question,** because I just needed to know this. It would appear that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4553129/4279) was incorrect and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1387222/4279) correct with respect to `os.name == 'posix'` on Cygwin. _May the upvotes shower you like rain._

Answer (score 6):

On Cygwin64,

```
import os; print  os.name; 
import sys; print sys.platform;
import platform; print platform.system()
```

yields:

```
posix
cygwin
CYGWIN_NT-6.1
```